# Display Non rectangular images in leaflets

Tags: leaflet

Is there any way to overlay non rectangular images in leaflet? Image edges do not make 90 degrees.

These images are from Modis. I am displaying a base map from openstreetmap, and use `L.ImageOverlay` function to add an image. `L.ImageOverlay` takes a bound specified by just 2 points. It assumes that the image is rectangular, but the images from Modis are non-rectangular i.e the angles made by the corners are acute or obtuse, so the bounds should really take at least 3 points.

Here is the code snippet

```
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>; contributors', 
    osm = L .tileLayer(osmUrl, { maxZoom : 8, attribution : osmAttrib });  
var map = new L.Map('map');  
map.addLayer(osm);  
var ovr = new L.ImageOverlay('../myimg.jpeg', bounds, {opacity : 1,interactive : true});  
map.addLayer(ovr)
```

Comment: Just did. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks to Ivan Sanchez, here is one solution :- https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated

Comment: See also http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tileimage-display and in particular https://github.com/publiclab/Leaflet.DistortableImage